# How to debug why the map job fails after multiple retries

Tags: java, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop-yarn, mapper

I wrote a mapreduce job to scan an hbase table for a certain time range to count certain elements we need for analysis.

Mappers in the MR job keeps failing but I don't know why.  Seems like each time I run the job, a different number of mappers fail.  The YARN log (see below) from Cloudera manager isn't helpful in pointing what the problem is, although, someone said I might be running out of memory.

It seems to retry multiple times but each time it fails.  What do I need to do to make it stop failing or how can I log things to help me better determine what is happening?

Below is a log from YARN for one of the mappers that failed.

> Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException:
>   Failed after attempts=36, exceptions: Thu Jun 15 16:26:57 PDT 2017,
>   null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000,
>   callDuration=60301: row '152_p3401.db161139.sjc102.dbi_1496271480' on
>   table 'dbi_based_data' at
>   region=dbi_based_data,151_p3413.db162024.iad4.dbi_1476974340,1486675565213.d83250d0682e648d165872afe5abd60e., hostname=hslave35118.ams9.mysecretdomain.com,60020,1483570489305,
>   seqNum=19308931 at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.throwEnrichedException(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:276)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:207)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:60)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.loadCache(ClientScanner.java:403)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:364)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableRecordReaderImpl.nextKeyValue(TableRecordReaderImpl.java:236)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableRecordReader.nextKeyValue(TableRecordReader.java:147)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase$1.nextKeyValue(TableInputFormatBase.java:216)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused
>   by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000,
>   callDuration=60301: row '152_p3401.db161139.sjc102.dbi_1496271480' on
>   table 'dbi_based_data' at
>   region=dbi_based_data,151_p3413.db162024.iad4.dbi_1476974340,1486675565213.d83250d0682e648d165872afe5abd60e., hostname=hslave35118.ams9.mysecretdomain.com,60020,1483570489305,
>   seqNum=19308931 at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:65)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Call to
>   hslave35118.ams9.mysecretdomain.com/10.216.35.118:60020 failed on
>   local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallTimeoutException:
>   Call id=12, waitTime=60001, operationTimeout=60000 expired. at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.wrapException(AbstractRpcClient.java:291)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1272)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:226)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:331)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:34094)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:219)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:64)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:360)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:334)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
>   ... 4 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallTimeoutException: Call id=12,
>   waitTime=60001, operationTimeout=60000 expired. at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.checkAndSetTimeout(Call.java:73) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1246)
>   ... 13 more

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like for my case I needed to extend the timeout setting.  In my Java program I had to add the following lines to make the exception go away:

```
    conf.set("hbase.rpc.timeout","90000");
    conf.set("hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period","90000");
```

The answer was found [on this link on Cloudera's site](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_hbase_scanner_heartbeat.html)